LED driver circuit /current source

I want to make a simple LED driver circuit. I did the simulation, but I'm not sure if it will work correctly. Do you have any suggestions for a similar circuit, or is this circuit good enough to work with?
My LED is 32 V 1.4 A 55 W
Note: I want to use the LED for camera which has 60 fps frame.

If you supply it with DC, frame rate won’t matter.

Yes, I’m using a DC source. I'm just worried about the heat that will be generated by the PNP transistor.

"I'm not sure if it will work correctly" - what is it you want it to do?

You can know exactly how much heat the transistor will dissipate. It's the emitter current times collector-emitter voltage.

Do you just want to drive it? Get a 1.4 A CC driver with at least 32 V compliance voltage. Do you need to dim it?

Given the high current a buck regulator would make more sense. Meanwell will sell you a DCDC driver for single digit dollars.

What is this 32 V LED exactly? Does it need a constant current driver or does it have one built in? Please post a link to a datasheet.

https://www.direnc.net/50w-beyaz-power-led-en this is the link

@jakop Can you please add any additional information such as links to datasheets to the question instead of in the comments. Thanks.

@jakop Thanks for the link to the device. I don't think anything else matters until you tell us how many of these you will be using in your lighting module and how you are going to dissipate 50 W per LED. That dissipation is going to be a serious problem to solve as they say you should (optimally) keep them at $60^\circ\text{C}$. Which doesn't provide much of a margin to work with. The current isn't the problem here. That's easily solved. I'd like to see proof that you have a dissipation plan that makes sense. And why aren't you buying something like a GVM?

A 1.4A current source can be done by Lm317 itself.
You can calculate sensing resistor as Rsense=1.25V/1.4A=0.9ohm (use 1ohm/4W
Since the Pmax of Lm317 is 20W the Vcc can up to 47V (20W/1.4A=14V max drop on Lm317 + 1.25V on Rsense + 32V on Led).


Yes, you can do a 1.4A current source with LM317, but is it possible or sensible in this case? The resistor needs to dlssipate 1.75W and has 1.25V drop. Recommended voltage over LM317 is 3V. It needs to dissipate 4.2W. If thermal resistance is 25 C/W, the LM317 junction temperature may need to be 125C which so it needs a big heatsink and good cooling so it does not go into thermal shutdown.

Hmm, my maximum DC voltage is 35V. It will work with low illumination.

@jakop What is the minimum Vcc? Is it a battery?

@MichalPodmanický no it is dc power supply the   minimum is 12 V
